# How to calculate correlation against 2 data frames and output by condition using R?

Tags: r, if-statement, correlation

I am going to calculate correlation between 2 gene expression data frames, which are protein and RNA data frames. Data shows here.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S5bYm8baqLf40KqmEbOO59YrDLp4sWnL/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wmZF4v8Ehq2giKldFWHv6UUBzu8Ncsy2/view

Rownames are gene, and colnames are samples. let's say, gene1 represents gene in 1st df, gene2 represents gene in 2nd df.

The output I want is a table, only contain the correlation meet the condition, not all correlation value. It looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUX87.png)

Here is what and how I do:

A. I need to calculate correlation of gene1 and gene2.

B. And I want to filter that |correlation(gene1, gene1)|<0.3 & |correlation(gene1, gene2)|>0.6, which means correlation of same gene in 2 df smaller than 0.3, and correlation of different gene in 2 df higher than 0.6

C. Return a table with columns are 'gene, gene, correlation', the output I want is a table like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUX87.png)

This is my code, which cannot make what I need, and there are more than 10,000 rows and 77 cols of each data frames, the job was been killed in GPU, which run more than 2 hours, please make code easy and use less memory as less as possible.

```
func.cor3 <- function(x,y){#func.cor
na1 <- which(is.na(x)==TRUE)
na2 <- which(is.na(y)==TRUE)
nas <- union(na1,na2)
if(length(nas)!=0){
  x <- x[-nas]
  y <- y[-nas]
}


nn <- cor(x,y)
nn <- round(nn,5)
nn <- format(nn, nsmall = 5)

if(nn>0.6 & nn< -0.6){
  w <-as.character(str_c(nn,"_r1p2>0.6"))
  return(w)
}
else if(nn<0.3 & nn> -0.3){
  w <-as.character(str_c(nn,"_r1p1<0.3"))
  return(w)
}else{

}

P2 <- P[,-1]
rownames(P2) <- P[,1]

nn <- setdiff(colnames(P2),colnames(R2))
ns <- vector();n=1
for (i in 1:length(nn)) {
nn.i <- nn[i]
w.i <- which(colnames(P2)==nn.i)
ns[n] <- w.i
n=n+1
}
P2 <- P2[,-ns]

nk <- colnames(P2)
ns <- order(nk)
P2 <- P2[,ns]


P2_1000 <- P2[1:1000,1:77]# try first 1000 rows of data

R <- read.csv(file = "RNA_Breast_2.csv",header = TRUE)
R2 <- R[,-1]
rownames(R2) <- R[,1]

nk <- colnames(R2)
ns <- order(nk)
R2 <- R2[,ns]

R2_1000 <- R2[1:1000,]

D_M <- matrix(rep(NA,3*nrow(R2_1000)*nrow(P2_1000)),ncol =3 )
colnames(D_M) <- c("gene1_RNA","gene_Protein","correlation")

n=1
for (i in 1:nrow(R2_1000)) {
for (j in 1:nrow(P2_1000)) {
  D_M[n,1] <- rownames(R2_1000)[i]
  D_M[n,2] <- rownames(P2_1000)[j]
  D_M[n,3] <- func.cor3(as.numeric(R2_1000[i,]),as.numeric(P2_1000[j,]))
  n=n+1
}
}

D_M
```

Comment: Hi Shuyang Deng, thanks for showing the code. It's not quite useful if we don't have the data you are working with. How about explaining the problem you have with say 10-20 genes, and showing the expected output? I don't think running that will kill your cpu yet :)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your quick reply, I have upload the data and a picture how the output I want. And I have run it in GPU, after 2 hours, the job was killed...I am wondering if there are better code edition. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I took a look at the txt files. The rownames and the colnames don't match at all. I think they are in different format. Please sort that out. And also, to get better responses, I suggest narrowing down your problem to just calculating the correlation?

Comment: I have make col and row match, thx.